# Big O of Finding the Intersection in two Unsorted Arrays Using filter() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity, big-o

I just started learning Big O notation and I'm trying to understand the Big O of different functions to see which one is better.

I'm struggling to calculate the **time and space complexity** for the following code.

```
function findCommonElem(arr1, arr2) { 
  let result = arr1.filter(x => arr2.includes(x));
  console.log(result);
}

  findCommonElem(arr1, arr2);
```

From what I understand, common array methods like `filter()` usually have a big O of `O(n)` so in this case, it'd be `O(m+n)` depending on the length of each array. However, I could be super wrong.

Can someone explain, please? Thanks so much!

Bonus question: Compared to sorting the arrays then using a while loop for the same function, which one would be considered as "better"?

Comment: Why `m + n`? `findCommonElem` compares every (in the worst case) element of `arr1` with every element of `arr2` -> `m * n`

Comment: Isn't it O(m * n)?

Comment: As the Array filter function has to pass through all the entries so do the Array Includes . complexity will be O(m*n)

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply @Andreas and @radulle! 
That does make sense. As I mentioned, I could be super wrong LOL so thanks for correcting! :)

Comment: Doesn't it also make a difference which way around you have the arrays?  If arr2 is bigger than arr1, you should be applying the filter to arr2 instead and using arr1 for the includes() test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The above function has a time complexity of `O(M * N)`.

But can you make this solution more efficient?

**Yes. You can reduce it to `O(M + N)`.**

**TLDR: Use a hash table to achieve linear time complexity `O(M + N).`**

---

#### Approach 1

Check every elements of array 1 with every element of array 2. (This is the approach you're using.)

```js
function findCommonElem(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(x => arr2.includes(x));
}

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20];

console.log(findCommonElem(arr1, arr2)); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

- Time complexity = `O(M * N)`

  - Every element from array 1 is checked with every element of array 2 at the worst case. So, it's M * N.
- Space compexity = `O(M)` or `O(N)`

  - At most, all of the elements from one of the either arrays could be in the intersection.

#### Approach 2

Use a [hash map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to linearize the nested loop. First, populate the hash map with array 1 elements. Then check through the array 2 using the map to find the intersection.

```js
function findCommonElem(arr1, arr2) {
  const map = new Map();

  arr1.forEach(item => map.set(item, true));

  return arr2.filter(item => map.has(item));
}

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20];

console.log(findCommonElem(arr1, arr2)); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

The above function returns the same output. But here's the difference - **the nested loop is reduced to two linear loops for the arrays. This means both arrays are traversed only once.**

- Time complexity = `O(M + N)`

  - Array 1 is traversed once (M elements).
  - Array 2 is traversed once (N elements).
  - Checking if the map contains the element with `map.has()` takes constant time `O(1)`.
  - Total run time = M + N
- Space compexity = `O(M)` or `O(N)`

  - Space complexity is still the same here, because space needed for the new hash map is either `O(M)` or `O(N)`. And our intermediate array takes either `O(M)` or `O(N)`. Which is still the same.

**Bonus:** Don't know much about how hash maps work internally? Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shs0KM3wKv8).

#### Approach 3

Use [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The set data structure is best for this use case as you don't need the mapped value (the `true` value) in approach 2.

```js
function findCommonElem(arr1, arr2) {
  const set = new Set(arr1);

  return arr2.filter(item => set.has(item));
}

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20];

console.log(findCommonElem(arr1, arr2)); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

This uses relatively lesser space but the algorithmic complexity of TC and SC are still same.

- Time complexity = `O(M + N)`
- Space compexity = `O(M)` or `O(N)`

Thanks to Nick Parsons for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

let's say that `arr1.length` is n and `arr2.length` is m.
so the `filter` function run the lambda function you wrote for each item in `arr1`. The lambda function checks if an item is in the `arr2` and in the worst case where it didn't find it the function ran on all the array so m times.
therefore `arr1.filter(x => arr2.includes(x))` run at the worst case O(n*m).

as for the space complexity, the `filter` function creates a new array and in the worst case that array size is as big as the original so the space complexity is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

As it correctly mentioned, big O here would be equal to `O(n*m)`, here is an explanation for this:

1. `arr1.filter` complexity is O(n)
2. `arr2.includes` complexity is O(n) as well

However for each iteration in .filter you execute each time arr2.includes, which leads to `O(n) * O(n) = O(n * m)`

You may increase performance if you replace for example arr2 with JS Set. JS Set.has complexity is `O(1)`, so using Set instead of arr2 should help you to achieve `O(n)` complexity.

I believe I cannot answer on sorting question, cause I haven't understood clearly what you mean.

Comment: "complexity is O(n) as well" isn't this only true if `n >= m`? wouldn't it be more accurate to say "arr2.includes has a complexity of O(m)"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For my last question,I was comparing to the code below. If I replace arr2 with Set, does the performance exceed the sorting method shown below? 

`function findCommonElem(arr1, arr2) {
  arr1.sort((a, b) => a - b); //O(n log n)
  arr2.sort((a, b) => a - b); //O(m log m)
  let result = [];
  let i = 0, j = 0;

  while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
    if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
      result.push(arr1[i]);
      i++;
      j++;
    } else if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
      i++;
    } else {
      j++;
    }
  } //(O(m+n))
  console.log(result);
}`

Comment: @supvicky this code would have a better big O notation. it would actually be O(n log(n) + m log(m))