# How can I see if Object Array has elements in Another Object Array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to tell if an object array has any common elements to another object array, and what that object intersect is? (like a Contains function). In the example below,ProductId3 in Object Array 1, is also contained in Object Array 2.

I'm thinking of using a double for loop . However is there a more efficient/optimal way, or shorthand ecma or lodash function?

**We are checking all object members, not just ProductId.**

```
array1.forEach(arr1 => {
  array2.forEach(arr2 => { 
       if (arr1.productId === arr2.productId && 
           arr1.productName === arr2.productName ...
```

**Object Array 1:**

```
[
{
    ProductId: 50,
    ProductName: 'Test1',
    Location: 77,
    Supplier: 11,
    Quantity: 33
},
{
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25
}
]
```

**Object Array 2:**

```
[
{
    ProductId: 1,
    ProductName: 'ABC',
    Location: 3,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 52
},
{
    ProductId: 2,
    ProductName: 'DEF',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 2,
    Quantity: 87
},
{
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25
},
{
    ProductId: 4,
    ProductName: 'XYZ',
    Location:  5,
    Supplier: 6,
    Quantity: 17
}
]
```

**Resources:**

[How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

[Javascript: Using `.includes` to find if an array of objects contains a specific object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187940/javascript-using-includes-to-find-if-an-array-of-objects-contains-a-specific)

Comment: we are doing a duplicate check for our web ui validation cc @RuanMendes I have a solution written, however checking if there is anything more optimal/efficient/shorthand, thanks

Comment: we are checking all object members cc @RuanMendes

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64101969/14671235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Is there a way to tell if an object array has any common elements to another object array ?*** - Yes you can achieve this with the help of [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false.

```js
const array1 = [{
  ProductId: 50,
  ProductName: 'Test1',
  Location: 77,
  Supplier: 11,
  Quantity: 33
}, {
  ProductId: 3,
  ProductName: 'GHI',
  Location: 1,
  Supplier: 4,
  Quantity: 25
}];

const array2 = [{
  ProductId: 1,
  ProductName: 'ABC',
  Location: 3,
  Supplier: 4,
  Quantity: 52
}, {
  ProductId: 2,
  ProductName: 'DEF',
  Location: 1,
  Supplier: 2,
  Quantity: 87
}, {
  ProductId: 3,
  ProductName: 'GHI',
  Location: 1,
  Supplier: 4,
  Quantity: 25
}, {
  ProductId: 4,
  ProductName: 'XYZ',
  Location:  5,
  Supplier: 6,
  Quantity: 17
}];

const isCommonProducts = array2.some(({ ProductId }) => array1.map(obj => obj.ProductId).includes(ProductId));

console.log(isCommonProducts);
```

***Update :*** As per the author comment, we have to check all the properties of an object. Hence, we can achieve that by comparing the JSON string by converting the object into a string.

Live Demo :

```js
const array1 = [{
  ProductId: 50,
  ProductName: 'Test1',
  Location: 77,
  Supplier: 11,
  Quantity: 33
}, {
  ProductId: 3,
  ProductName: 'GHI',
  Location: 1,
  Supplier: 4,
  Quantity: 25
}];

const array2 = [{
  ProductId: 1,
  ProductName: 'ABC',
  Location: 3,
  Supplier: 4,
  Quantity: 52
}, {
  ProductId: 2,
  ProductName: 'DEF',
  Location: 1,
  Supplier: 2,
  Quantity: 87
}, {
  ProductId: 3,
  ProductName: 'GHI',
  Location: 1,
  Supplier: 4,
  Quantity: 25
}, {
  ProductId: 4,
  ProductName: 'XYZ',
  Location:  5,
  Supplier: 6,
  Quantity: 17
}];

const getFilteredProducts = array2.filter(productObj => JSON.stringify(array1).indexOf(JSON.stringify(productObj)) !== -1);

console.log(getFilteredProducts);
```

Comment: You can change "{ productID }" to just " product " within the parenthesis & do a check on all necessary pieces! (  using product.whateverPartOfTheObject  )

Comment: @mattsmith5 Thanks for pointing that out! I updated the answer as per your requirement. Hope it will work as per your expectation now.

Answer (score 2):

If we can assume that each array's elements (we will call them *sub-dictionaries*) contain exactly the same keys in the same order, then this is my idea:

1. Convert each array into a new array whose elements are the JSON representations of the original sub-dictionaries values. This is an o(N) operation performed twice.
2. Of the new, converted arrays find the shortest one. Convert the other into a set. This is also o(N).
3. For each element of the shorter converted array, check to see if the set contains this value. This is also o(N).

```js
let arr1 = [
{
    ProductId: 50,
    ProductName: 'Test1',
    Location: 77,
    Supplier: 11,
    Quantity: 33
},
{
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25
}
];

let arr2 = [
{
    ProductId: 1,
    ProductName: 'ABC',
    Location: 3,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 52
},
{
    ProductId: 2,
    ProductName: 'DEF',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 2,
    Quantity: 87
},
{
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25
},
{
    ProductId: 4,
    ProductName: 'XYZ',
    Location:  5,
    Supplier: 6,
    Quantity: 17
}
];

// Convert each sub-array's values to JSON string:
let arr1New = arr1.map(function(arr) {return JSON.stringify(Object.values(arr));});
let arr2New = arr2.map(function(arr) {return JSON.stringify(Object.values(arr));});

// Find shortest array of JSON strings:
const l1 = arr1New.length;
const l2 = arr2New.length;
// enumerate shortest list
let list, set, l, arr;
if (l1 <= l2) {
    list = arr1New;
    set = new Set(arr2New);
    l = l1;
    arr = arr1;
}
else {
    list = arr2New;
    set = new Set(arr1New);
    l = l2;
    arr = arr2;
}

for(let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (set.has(list[i])) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

**Update**

If the sub-dictionary keys are not necessarily in order, then we have to create new sub-dictionaries from these where the keys are in order:

```JavaScript
// Create function to create new dictionaries sorted by keys

function sort_dict(d) {
    items = Object.keys(d).map(function(key) {
        return [key, d[key]];
    });
    items.sort(function(first, second) {
        return first[0] < second[0] ? -1 : (first[0] > second[0] ? 1 : 0);
    });
    sorted_dict = {};
    items.forEach(function(x) {
        sorted_dict[x[0]] = x[1];
    });
    return(sorted_dict);
}

// And then we have these modified lines:
// Convert each sub-array's values to JSON string:
let arr1New = arr1.map(function(arr) {return JSON.stringify(Object.values(sort_dict(arr)));});
let arr2New = arr2.map(function(arr) {return JSON.stringify(Object.values(sort_dict(arr)));});
```

**Modified Code**

```js
let arr1 = [
{
    ProductId: 50,
    ProductName: 'Test1',
    Location: 77,
    Supplier: 11,
    Quantity: 33
},
{
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25,
    ProductId: 3 // Not in the same order as the others
}
];

let arr2 = [
{
    ProductId: 1,
    ProductName: 'ABC',
    Location: 3,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 52
},
{
    ProductId: 2,
    ProductName: 'DEF',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 2,
    Quantity: 87
},
{
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25
},
{
    ProductId: 4,
    ProductName: 'XYZ',
    Location:  5,
    Supplier: 6,
    Quantity: 17
}
];


function sort_dict(d) {
    items = Object.keys(d).map(function(key) {
        return [key, d[key]];
    });
    items.sort(function(first, second) {
        return first[0] < second[0] ? -1 : (first[0] > second[0] ? 1 : 0);
    });
    sorted_dict = {};
    items.forEach(function(x) {
        sorted_dict[x[0]] = x[1];
    });
    return(sorted_dict);
}

// Convert each sub-array's values to JSON string:
let arr1New = arr1.map(function(arr) {return JSON.stringify(Object.values(sort_dict(arr)));});
let arr2New = arr2.map(function(arr) {return JSON.stringify(Object.values(sort_dict(arr)));});

// Find shortest array of JSON strings:
const l1 = arr1New.length;
const l2 = arr2New.length;
// enumerate shortest list
let list, set, l, arr;
if (l1 <= l2) {
    list = arr1New;
    set = new Set(arr2New);
    l = l1;
    arr = arr1;
}
else {
    list = arr2New;
    set = new Set(arr1New);
    l = l2;
    arr = arr2;
}

for(let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (set.has(list[i])) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice method but it will fail if the properties are not all in the same order.

Comment: @caTS Yes, that is so and I have implied as much in my answer. I have updated the answer to handle the situation where the properties are not in the same order.

Comment: this is great code , what are thoughts on Rohìt Jíndal answer above?

Comment: After a quick look it *appears* to me that his solution is efficient but only works if all properties of each object are in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple yet reasonably fast solution, you can (1) use a `Set` of `productId`s from the first array, then (2) `filter` the second array based on the ids from the first one, this you only have to go over each array once `O(n)`.

```js
let arr1 = [
  {
    ProductId: 50,
    ProductName: "Test1",
    Location: 77,
    Supplier: 11,
    Quantity: 33,
  },
  {
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: "GHI",
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25,
  },
];

let arr2 = [
  {
    ProductId: 1,
    ProductName: "ABC",
    Location: 3,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 52,
  },
  {
    ProductId: 2,
    ProductName: "DEF",
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 2,
    Quantity: 87,
  },
  {
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: "GHI",
    Location: 1,
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25,
  },
  {
    ProductId: 4,
    ProductName: "XYZ",
    Location: 5,
    Supplier: 6,
    Quantity: 17,
  },
];

const getCommonItems = (arr1, arr2) => {
  let firstIdSet = new Set(arr1.map((product) => product.ProductId)); //1
  return arr2.filter((product) => firstIdSet.has(product.ProductId)); //2
};

console.log(getCommonItems(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: Isn't this code just checking for equal ProductID values whereas the OP wants all properties to be equal?

Comment: Correct @Booboo

Comment: Then I don't see how this is a solution if you are not verifying that all properties are equal.

Comment: Agreed @Booboo we need to check all properties

Answer (score -1):

If you want a deep equality comparison(for nested objects or for all `(key, value)` pairs), I would suggest a slightly better approach which is using the `base64` encoding/decoding to improve on comparison performance.
So my approach is to:

1. merge the arrays and convert the object to base64 strings.
2. Group the recurrences together
3. Filter on duplicates
4. revert the base64 strings into their original object.

```js
const convertObjToBase64 = o => btoa(JSON.stringify(o));
const convertBase64ToObj = str => JSON.parse(atob(str));
const arrayToObjCount = arr => arr.reduce((res, v) => {
  res[v] = (res[v] ?? 0) + 1;
  return res;
}, {});

const findDuplicateObjectsInMultipleArrays = (...arrays) => {
  const base64Array = Array.from(arrays.flat(), convertObjToBase64);
  const objCount = arrayToObjCount(base64Array);
  const duplicates = Object.entries(objCount).reduce((prev, [k, v]) => {
    if (v > 1) {
      prev.push(convertBase64ToObj(k));
    }
    return prev;
  }, []);
  return duplicates;
}

let arr1 = [{
    ProductId: 50,
    ProductName: 'Test1',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 77,
      LocationName: 'Location 77'
    },
    Supplier: 11,
    Quantity: 33
  },
  {
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 1,
      LocationName: 'Location 1'
    },
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25
  }
];

let arr2 = [{
    ProductId: 1,
    ProductName: 'ABC',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 3,
      LocationName: 'Location 3'
    },
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 52
  },
  {
    ProductId: 2,
    ProductName: 'DEF',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 1,
      LocationName: 'Location 1'
    },
    Supplier: 2,
    Quantity: 87
  },
  {
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 1,
      LocationName: 'Location 1'
    },
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25
  },
  {
    ProductId: 4,
    ProductName: 'XYZ',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 5,
      LocationName: 'Location 5'
    },
    Supplier: 6,
    Quantity: 17
  }
];

let arr3 =[ 
  {
    ProductId: 2,
    ProductName: 'DEF',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 1,
      LocationName: 'Location 1'
    },
    Supplier: 2,
    Quantity: 87
  },
  {
    ProductId: 3,
    ProductName: 'GHI',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 2,
      LocationName: 'Location 2'
    },
    Supplier: 4,
    Quantity: 25
  },
   {
    ProductId: 4,
    ProductName: 'XYZ',
    Location: {
      LocationId: 6,
      LocationName: 'Location 5'
    },
    Supplier: 6,
    Quantity: 17
  }
];
console.log(findDuplicateObjectsInMultipleArrays(arr1, arr2, arr3));
```

Answer (score -1):

I will post two solutions:

**First Solution is readable one**
Code is not 100% performance optimized, but it is readable and elegant.

[Playground link with working code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQRhgXhgbQLACgDeeMxMACgiACYCuwUAkpQFwwCsADADREnlW1QAcnAC2AUxYByACpjoySd1wkYAGRDA4UAJbgWAdn1KVAZWoAHcwBttYhC2TJjJAIrU4YHVACeLAMx+eAC+SoTKvBQ0dIz+zsR8UUKiEjCSAOIAEvSKPMTqmjp6ME65MGaWNnYsACxxMG4eXr4wAEyswXgAunh4oJCwiAgt6Fh4YSoJAjHFdZN0wuJSAIIAQgDCOeF5Glq6YLGl5da29jC1pQ2e2j4srC3BoaVzDMyts5ECCymSACIAogAxTYqfK7IolLZlCzHKpvC7uK43GAADn0DzGTw+0Vefne-HmySkmWydVBhX2M0O0Mqp3OkMuTRYbXRBEx+JeNTxiS+UgAGgBNABawJIZL2LDYdSONJYADY6gzrs1kGjcEEuj1cD5zGIYPQoGIRCNxmQsRyYGBqCIAEZ2ADcPGePJg0AQ2jAAHMHeExUVLTb7TxpScWP7bQhvcRFUiw4G1Zq+tB4AgxNIABZiEzJEYACjgLA83k4MGtBbA3gAlOgAHwwE2J2Aga0AKyWfHMEBGAHkW2I6AA6ADWYm8EDzFf7ADNtFYDQgc8PvDWYNqxCBJ-BMIvOjAAIRoDAAIkn1DAdD2h4rPAbMCbzZW7c7GB7zb7UCHI7H1on09ndgXI7Lqu64lluI47vuR4nme5KXpqxDaBuOZ3m2FAdv2VhiJ6UBpnuB63i2D5oRAGFYR6OFViaxAplA1AIGAMCTnAVgQGIkYwOquA8DRdEMShj79mIABudjeDmObmGhXxVmgtZwJgkkgOYXw7geGDWgpUnJJ0V7xlxuA3h6YgMJ4disee4C5oMcDeMgLBLEgNkADyFtWxbWd4LT2Y53gueW1YybWJo8fRyYIDZyBTjOc55sg+qGsuHktP2EAgOIeYtPFRqycmqYZlm6VwHFBoiO5mUlRWlXepxvTgEmKYQNQs4jEZJlzuZ5J5kgThhS0FberVkAgJhGEgB6OYNU1UD9XgQA)

First, we need a method that compares two objects of any type. The method compares the first-level properties, so if we have nested object properties, it will compare them by reference.

```js
const areTheSame = (a: any, b: any) => {
  const objAProps = Object.keys(a).filter(key => typeof a[key] !== "function")
  const objBProps = Object.keys(b).filter(key => typeof b[key] !== "function")

  if (objAProps.length !== objBProps.length) {
    return false;
  }

  return objAProps.every((propName) => a[propName] === b[propName]);
}
```

And then we can implement readable intersect method which will work for any array types:

```js
const getIntersection = (array1: Array<any>, array2: Array<any>) => {
  return array1.filter(a1Item => array2.some(a2Item => areTheSame(a1Item, a2Item)));
}
```

**The Second solution is performance-oriented, its drawback is that it is not so readable**

First, we calculate the has for all objects, then within a single forEach loop we can identify the intersection based on that Hash. I have used md5, but any hash algorithm or library can be used.

Hers is [stack blitz link playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-g2ggt5?file=index.ts). It can be run, ignore the import error.

```js
const getArrayIntersection = (
  firstArray: Array<any>,
  secondArray: Array<any>
) => {
  const array1Hashed = firstArray.map((i) => md5(JSON.stringify(i)));
  const array2Set = new Set(secondArray.map((i) => md5(JSON.stringify(i))));

  const result: Array<any> = [];

  array1Hashed.forEach((itemHash, index) => {
    if (array2Set.has(itemHash)) {
      result.push(firstArray[index]);
    }
  });
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to piggyback @Rohìt Jíndal, you can check if an array has a specific object like so:

```
const resultObj = arr1.filter(obj => obj.id=== "whatever" && obj.productname == "whatever") // ETC ETC
```